# can I use sftp to get a local copy of all the names and structure of a remote site but no content?

Tags: ssh, sftp

I'd like to create folders and TOUCH files so that I have a local mirror of their names, but none of their content. Is that possible via sftp?

Comment: This is too vague - *"use sftp"* - are you referring to SFTP protocol in general or to a particular SFTP client implementation (OpenSSH `sftp`)? What platform are you on?

Comment: i'm on osx (/usr/bin/sftp), the server is on debian 8. i can sftp already to transfer the files themselves, and perform `get`s to pull files and `ls` to list remote files; I guess I want to somehow use `ls` to pull the file list then use that as an input to `touch` on the local machine, recurse to all folders (making folders locally). alternative to sftp welcomed.